# TFS2010 TF215097:No Endpoint Listening 

Tags: tfs

Ok I have a TFS2010 Build Controller Setup as follows

I have 3 VM's each running the TFS Build Host Service

- 1 has 1 controller and 1 agent
- 2 have 2 Build Agents each.

Most of the time (7\10 builds) it comes back with the following error message

```
TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition BUILD_DEFINITION: There was no endpoint listening at http://MACHINE1:9191/Build/v3.0/Services/Controller/14 that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

and there is no errors when i do get this message. the following is the config file that i have created

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
    <add key="traceWriter" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <switches>
            <add name="BuildServiceTraceLevel" value="4"/>
            <add name="API" value="4"/>
            <add name="Authentication" value="4"/>
            <add name="Authorization" value="4"/>
            <add name="Database" value="4"/>
            <add name="General" value="4"/>
            <add name="traceLevel" value="4"/>
        </switches>
        <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
            <listeners>
                <add name="myListener" type="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationTextWriterTraceListener,Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" initializeData="c:\logs\TFSBuildServiceHost.exe.log" />
         <remove name="Default" />
            </listeners>
        </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

I do have my own custom activities in my build process but this does not seem to be a problem as sometimes the build actually does go. I have tried refreshing the template as some sites suggest.

Has anyone come across a solution for this problem? or can anyone tell me how to catch these errors when they happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be an issue with a third-party firewall on your build agents that is not allowing communication from the TFS server. Try disabling any firewalls and see if that resolves your problem.

Comment: I have no firewalls turned on. each of the servers is internal.

Comment: It seems that when I kick a build from the WEB portal the build always works so i can only presume that it is some network issue we are having where some part is blocking the communication